# ReactJS Match props not being passed to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a route like this

Dashboard.js

```
<Route path="/dashboard/:user_id" render={(props) =>  <Profile user={this.props.user} {...this.props}/>}/>
```

as you can see i am passing the props of `Dashboard` component to `Profile` Component, On react documentation when you pass the props the match Object is also passed I want to access the `match` object from the `Profile`

But i get `undefined` on Profile component when accessing `match.params`

```
componentDidMount(){
   console.log(this.props.match.params) // Undefined
}
```

When i check the react dev tools the `Profile` component indeed didn't received the match object but when i check the route in react dev tool there is the `match.params` with the current parameter

From React Dev tools

the `<Route/>` line gives me this

```
Props
 path: "/dashboard/:user_id"
 render: render()
State
 match: {…}
   isExact: true
   params: {…}
     user_id: "5af13d60f3957c11e46510ad"
   path: "/dashboard/:user_id"
   url: "/dashboard/5af13d60f3957c11e46510ad"
```

As you can see match is present

While the `Profile` component doesn't have the params

```
match: {…}
 isExact: true
 params: {…}
    Empty object
 path: "/dashboard"
 url: "/dashboard"
```

Comment: I believe it should be `<Route path="/dashboard/:user_id" render={(props) =>  <Profile user={props.user} {...props}/>}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Profile component try to change {...this.props} to {...props}

Comment: Awesome it works, but may i ask what is the difference between `...this.props` to `...props` ?

Comment: this.props will get props for parent component, and props refers to props in Router.